# How can write '<' in HTML tag?

Tags: html, text, tags

I wanna write text between of a tag that it should have < . but I can write it

for example

```
<div class="SampleDiv">Text1<Text2<Text3</div>
```

How can fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read about [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). In this case, the `<` character should be replaced with `&lt;`

Answer (score 0):

Just use & together with #60; instead of the "<" or & together with #62 instead of the ">".